# Why do we care about the annihilator of a row space?

Tags: linear-algebra

It's natural to find the subspace annihilated by the set of linear functionals because the subspace in this case conceptually represents the solution space. However, what does it mean to find the annihilator of a row space? **I think the row space is the one that should be treated as the annihilator**—because $(A_{i1},...,A_{in})$ is uniquely paired with linear functionals $f_{i}(x_{1},...,x_{n})=A_{i1}x_{1}+\cdots +A_{in}x_{n}.$ If we want to find $\alpha$ such that $$f_{i}(\alpha)=0\quad i=1,...,m$$ we need to focus on finding the subspace annihilated by a row space, not the annihilator of a row space, I suppose. Here's the quote from the book that puzzled me a lot:

> Now one may look at the system of linear equations from the 'dual' point of view. That is, suppose that we are given $m$ vectors in $F^{n}$ $$\alpha_{i}=(A_{i1},\ldots,A_{in})$$ and **we wish to find the annihilator of the subspace spanned by these vectors**. Since a typical linear functional on $F^{n}$ has the form $$f(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})=c_{1}x_{1}+\cdots+c_{n}x_{n}$$ the condition that $f$ be in this annihilator is that $$\sum_{j=1}^{n}A_{ij}c_{j},\quad i=1,\ldots,m$$ that is, that $(c_{1},\ldots,c_{n})$ be a solution of the system $AX=0.$ From this point of view, row-reduction gives us a systemic method of finding the annihilator of the subspace spanned by a given finite set of vectors in $F_{n}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the common conventions, we think of column vectors as elements of the vector space $\mathbb{F}^n$ and of row vectors as elements of the dual space $(\mathbb{F}^n)^{*}$. Each row vector $v = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ defines uniquely a linear functional $\varphi_v \colon \mathbb{F}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ on $\mathbb{F}^n$ by

$$ \varphi_v \left( \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ \dots \\ y_n \end{pmatrix} \right) = (x_1, \dots, x_n) \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ \dots \\ y_n \end{pmatrix} = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i $$

and all linear functionals are obtained in this way.

A subspace $V \subseteq \mathbb{F}^n$ can be described in two ways - as a span of a set of vectors ("a parametric description") or as a solution set of a linear system of equations ("an implicit description"). Passing from one description to the other involves calculating a basis of an annihilator of the appropriate set of row / column vectors.

Let me demonstrate this with an example. Consider the equation $x + y + z = 0$ on $\mathbb{F}^3$. The equation defines a two-dimensional subspace $V$ of $\mathbb{F}^3$ which is the same as the kernel of the linear functional $\varphi_{(1,1,1)}$ or the annihilator of the set $\{ (1,1,1) \}$ (where we identify $\left( \left( F^{n} \right)^{*} \right)^{*}$ with $\mathbb{F}^n$ so the annihilator is a subspace of column vectors). In this case, a basis of the annihilator is given for example by

$$ \operatorname{Ann}( (1,1,1) ) = \operatorname{span} \left \{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \right \}. $$

This gives us a parametric description of $V$ as a span of two linearly independent vectors:

$$ V = \left \{ t \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} + s \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \, : \, t,s \in \mathbb{F} \right \}. $$

Going the other way around, given a parametric description of $V$, we can calculate a basis for the annihilator of the spanning set of $V$ and obtain an implicit description of $V$ as a solution set of linear equations:

$$ \operatorname{Ann} \left( \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \right) = \operatorname{span} \{ (1,1,1) \}. $$

To summarize, calculating a basis for the annihilator of a set of row vectors is the same as finding a basis for the solution set defined by a system of equations (linear functionals) corresponding to the row vectors. Calculating a basis for the annihilator of a set of column vectors is the same as a finding a basis for the set of equations (linear functionals) the vectors satisfy resulting in a description of the span as a solution set of a linear system of equations.

Comment: Why do you say that **"the annihilator of the set $\{ (1,1,1) \}$" belongs to $\left( F^{n} \right)^{**}?$** I think it belongs to $\left( F^{n} \right)^{*}.$ Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: The annihilator of a subset of $V$ belongs to $V^{*}$. If we identify row vectors with linear functions (so $(1,1,1)$ is identified with $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} \mapsto x + y + z$), then the annihilator of a set of row vectors belongs a priori to $((\mathbb{F}_{\operatorname{col}}^n)^{*})^{*} = (\mathbb{F}_{\operatorname{row}}^n)^{*}$ but this space is naturally identified with $\mathbb{F}^n_{\operatorname{col}}$. The isomorphism between $\mathbb{F}^n_{\operatorname{row}}$ and $\mathbb{F}^n_{\operatorname{col}}$ is the transpose of vectors.

Comment: The annihilator of a subset of $V^{*}$ (a collection of functionals) is a subspace of $(V^{*})^{*}$ but this space can be naturally identified with $V$ and under this identification, the annihilator of a subset of linear functionals (equations) corresponds to the solution set of the equations.

Comment: If you would think of $(1,1,1)$ as a vector in $\mathbb{F}^n$ and not as a linear functional, then its annihilator would indeed be a subspace of $(\mathbb{F}^n)^{*}$. However, the convention I described in the beginning of the post would then require you to think of the vector as a column vector and not as a row vector.

Comment: If we choose not to differentiate between row vectors and column vectors, I see (loosely put) that they are solutions each other. Am I right?

Comment: Yep, you can think of it this way. Given a set of row/column vectors, their annihilator is the set of solutions for the system of linear equations determined by the vectors.

Comment: Thank you very very much. It helped me a lot.